# JavaFX include with the same controller instance

Tags: java, javafx, include, fxml

I have a JavaFX project with a view written in FXML and attached to a Controller. In this controller I have a heavy object that is used in almost every user interaction.

My view has a TabPane with different functionalities. The problem I have is that the FXML file is quite big, and I'd like to split in different subfiles (every tab would get one). I tried using `fx:include`.

The problem I have is that I have to attach those files to a controller, so I attach them using `fx:controller`. The problem is that statement creates a new instance of the controller, so I don't have access to the shared object.

Is there any way I can still use the same controller and `fx:include`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Single Controller

If you really need a single controller for all tabs, you could consider a programmatic approach. You could initialize the views manually and link them to the controller instance. You could create the following helper method and invoke it subsequently for each view (for ex: `loadAndLink(controller, "/com/ui/views/login.fxml")`.

```
public void loadAndLink(Object controller, String viewPath) {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(viewPath));
    loader.setController(controller);
    try {
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, that the `initialize(...)` method of the controller will be called for each view (on the `loader.setController(controller)` call), so you would want it to be idempotent. Also, in case of programmatic loading of FXML, you need to remove the `fx:controller` tag from them. And also make sure that the `fx:id`s of all the elements across all the views have unique values.

#### Nested Controllers

On the other hand, if your FXML file is quite big then the controller is probably also. Consider using a separate nested controller (what this `fx:include` is for) for each tab. You can have links to the nested controllers from the parent one if you set them `fx:id`:

Parent FXML:

```
...
<fx:include fx:id="embeddedView" source="SomeOtherView.fxml"/>
...
```

Parent Controller:

```
...
@FXML
private Parent embeddedView;
...
```

Comment: I've implemented it using nested controllers and everything seems to work correctly. Thanks!